# select value form one table update value for fetched value in single query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two tables request and details.request table id is foreign key for details table I want I have price(321) and request_id(1819AM002) value.I want to fetch value id using request_id in request table update price field value in details table in single query.Is it possible to achieve in single query

```
 request table  
  id request_id  name  type
  1 1819AM001    XXX    A
  2 1819AM002    YYY    A

 Details table
 id request_id  price
  1  2           133
```

Comment: you want to use query builder and get something like update ... where ... select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DB::table('details')
    ->join('request', 'details.request_id', 'request.id')
    ->where('request.request_id', '1819AM002')
    ->update(['price' => 321]);
```